# ansible issue when using ansible.builtin.shell

Tags: shell, echo, ansible

```
$ ansible all -m ansible.builtin.shell  -a 'echo $TERM'
ERROR! this task 'ansible.builtin.shell' has extra params, which is only
allowed in the following modules: import_role, win_command,
include_vars, include_tasks, raw, win_shell, command, add_host, 
meta, include_role, shell, import_tasks, group_by, set_fact, script, include
```

can anyone help me to find out whats the issue

this is the one with `-vvv` tag

```
$ ansible -vvv centos -m ansible.builtin.shell  -a 'echo $TERM'
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/chandru/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) [GCC 9.3.0]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
ERROR! this task 'ansible.builtin.shell' has extra params, which is only allowed in the following modules: group_by, include_tasks, set_fact, raw, add_host, win_shell, win_command, include_vars, meta, import_role, command, script, include, shell, import_tasks, include_role
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to a bug in Ansible which was introduced as part of the transition to FQCN: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/71824

As a workaround, you can simply replace `ansible.builtin.shell` with the old-school `shell` name.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked

Answer (score -1):

u can try it:

```
 $ ansible all -m shell  -a 'echo $TERM'
```

---

my env:

```
root@ubuntu:~/ansiblelearn# ansible --version
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) [GCC 9.3.0]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).